# $\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I need to compute the mean value of this function:

${\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x}$

where $a$ is a constant and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind, but I have two main problems: I have no idea how to solve the integral and for the mean value I need to divide for the size of the integration interval which is infinite.

Now $x = k_1 + k_2 \tan \frac{\varphi}{2}$, where $k_1,k_2$ are constants, so I can solve the second problem by substituting and the mean value is given as:

$\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \exp\left[-\frac{a^2}{\left(k_1 + k_2 \tan \frac{\varphi}{2}\right)^2}\right] I_0\left[\frac{a^2}{\left(k_1 + k_2 \tan \frac{\varphi}{2}\right)^2}\right] \textrm{d}\varphi}$

Nevertheless this leads to a much more complicate integral and I have no clue on how to solve it.

If it can help the function inside the integral goes from $0$ to $1$ and its derivative should always be greater than $0$.

Comment: Integral diverges. If we talks about Bessel functions of the first kind (denoted as $J_0(x)$), $J_0(\frac{1}{x^2})\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: @Svyatoslav Agreed.  Therefore we need to figure out what "mean value" signifies here.

Comment: I assume you like to determine $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{w}\int_0^w {\exp \left( { - \frac{{a^2 }}{{x^2 }}} \right)I_0 \left( {\frac{{a^2 }}{{x^2 }}} \right)dx} =\frac{a}{2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{w}\int_{(a/w)^2 }^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^{ - 3/2} I_0 (t)dt} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha gives the antiderivative (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BBesselI%5B0%2C+a%5E2%2Fx%5E2%5D%2FE%5E%28a%5E2%2Fx%5E2%29%2Cx%5D))
$$I=\int\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x$$
$$I=\frac 1 x \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\left(2 a^2 I_1\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)+\left(2 a^2+x^2\right)
   I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\right)$$ So, for
$$J=\int_0^p\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x$$
$$J(p)=\frac 1 p \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{p^2}\right)\left(2 a^2 I_1\left(\frac{a^2}{p^2}\right)+\left(2 a^2+p^2\right)
   I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{p^2}\right)\right)-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} a$$

Using the asymptotics of Bessel functions

$$J(p)=p+\frac{a^2}{p}-\frac{a^4}{4 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} a$$ and, assuming that I properly understood,
$$\frac {J(p)} p=1-\frac{2a \sqrt 2 } {p\sqrt \pi }+\frac{a^2}{p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$

Using $a=\sqrt 2$ and $p=10^6$, the "exact" value is
$$0.9999977432436658089748512$$
while the above truncated expansion gives
$$\frac{500000000001}{500000000000}-\frac{1}{250000 \sqrt{\pi }}=0.9999977432436658089748522$$